# Linux signal:why my signal handler function works unproperly?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I modified the the default action associated with the SIGINT signal by using the signal function.
When I send SIGINT (type ctrl+c from keyboard) to the program for the first time,the signal handler function “handler2” works properly.But when I send SIGINT for the second time,the program exit and the signal handler function didn't work!
I thought the signal handler function works again,and the program willnot exit.Why my linux signal handler run only once?

Thank you for your help!

```
#include "csapp.h"

void handler2(int sig)
{
  int olderrno = errno;
  Sio_puts("Handler in ");
  Sio_putl(getpid());
  Sio_puts("\n");
  errno = olderrno;
}
int main()
{
  if (signal(SIGINT, handler2) == SIG_ERR)
    unix_error("signal error");
  while (1)
  {
    printf("Parent %d\n", (int)getpid());
    Sleep(5);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use `signal()` to create a signal handler, it's automatically removed when the signal occurs. Use `sigaction()` if you want control over this.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought, but the man page seems to differ: "...in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics." Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you're using glibc?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not the OP, just an interested bystander.

Comment: The best solution is to forget about `signal()` and use `sigaction()`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane  *This default behavior is provided as long as a suitable feature test macro is defined*.... *If such a feature test macro is not defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.*

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:**

> the behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions,
> and has also varied historically across different versions of
> Linux.  **Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead**

### Notes:

> **In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established
> using signal() was invoked by the delivery of a signal, the
> disposition of the signal would be reset to SIG_DFL, and the
> system did not block delivery of further instances of the signal.**
> This is equivalent to calling sigaction(2) with the following
> flags:
>
> ```
>    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER;
> ```
>
> System V also provides these semantics for signal().
>
> By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function
> does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls
> sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This
> default behavior is provided as long as a suitable feature test
> macro is defined: _BSD_SOURCE on glibc 2.19 and earlier or
> _DEFAULT_SOURCE in glibc 2.19 and later.  (By default, these
> macros are defined; see feature_test_macros(7) for details.)
> If such a feature test macro is not defined, then signal()
> provides System V semantics.

In short, the behaviour of `signal()` varies across UNIX systems. The only portable use is to set the disposition of a signal to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`. Use `sigaction(2)` instead.

And your code simply invokes undefined behaviour if it calls any *async-signal-unsafe* function.

A signal handler should only be setting a flag of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`, unless you really know what you are doing.